# hypothesis test whether pair of variables are close to either [0,1] and [1,0] or [1,0] and [0,1]

Tags: hypothesis-testing, multiple-comparisons

The observations I have are

{[(${x_1}_1$, ${x_1}_2$), (${y_1}_2$, ${y_1}_2$)], [(${x_2}_1$, ${x_2}_2$), (${y_2}_1$, ${y_2}_2$)], ... [(${x_n}_1$, ${x_n}_2$), (${y_n}_1$, ${y_n}_2$)]}

${x_i}_1$ + ${x_i}_2$ = ${y_i}_1$ + ${y_i}_2$ = 1

I want to test the hypothesis that ${x_i}_1$ is approximately equal to ${y_i}_j$, j is either 0 or 1, (which implies ${x_i}_2$ is approximately 1 - ${y_i}_{([j-1] mod 2)}$).

So for each $i$ $x_i$ and $y_i$ are very dependent but i dont care what the relationship of the depedence is (xi1=yi1 or xi1=yi2).

Any ideas how to rule out the null hypothesis that xi and yi are indepdent?